# How many primary cluster and secondary Cluster is supported by Global Database Network(GDN) in Alibaba Cloud?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

Recently I find an option named as GDN   in Alibaba Cloud Polar DB, Now before creating GDN network I have to know about what is GDN and how many primary and secondary(read-only) cluster is supported by Global Database Network(GDN)

Answer (score 0):

**What is GDN?**
Global database network (GDN) is the distributed of Apsara PolarDB clusters in different global regions where all are synchronized across the network.

**Why do you need GDN?**
When your business operates in multiple regions, you'd have applications deployed in multiple regions as well, but accessing your primary region database could create performance issues due to network latency. That's where GDN comes in. It synchronizes your primary cluster and secondary clusters with reduced latency.

You can have one primary cluster and up to 4 secondary clusters, but don't be confused with [multiple zones cluster](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/122182.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.73.5ef957065x9gw2), which is the [clustering](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/58769.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.879954.4.5ef957065x9gw2#task-1580301) between zones (high availability) in the same region, while GDN is for across regions.

You can [read more about GDN here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/160381.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.76.1f0a659azpEuvI).

Answer (score 0):

The GDN (Global Database Network) is a feature for Alibaba Cloud cloud-native database PolarDB, it can be used to deploy databases across multiple sites While managing the data synchronization between or among multiple database instances.
Currently, by default, it supports  1 primary PolarDB cluster and up to 4 secondary (read-only) clusters (if you need more secondary clusters, please submit a ticket) into a single PolarDB GDN.